# How can I add a meta field value to WP footer (inline)?

Tags: php, wordpress, schema

I have meta fields containg json schema mark up for products. I want to add these to the footer. I have tried using this function

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'insert_my_page_schema');
function insert_my_page_schema() {
if ( ! is_product() ) { 
return;
}
$schema = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'schema', true);
if ( ! $schema ) {
return;
}
echo $schema;
}
```

but this adds the code into the frontend, visible for the viewer of the site. How can I add mycustom field values inline to the footer, so that it is only visible for Google/in the source code, but not in frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be issue with wrapping schema code with `<script type="application/ld+json"></script>` tag, if you want to add schema then must need to wrap script tag as per this google reference example - https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/intro-structured-data

You may achieve this using anyone of below option

1. Wrap `<script type="application/ld+json">{your schema code here}</script>` in scheme field value from backend
2. You can wrap script tag in code itself `echo '<script type="application/ld+json">'. $schema .'</script>';` instead of `echo $schema;`

Comment: I am already adding the schema in the meta field value like this: <script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"https://schema.org", ...</script> but still it is displayed on frontend.

Comment: Never mind, your second option is working! So I have ermoved the <script> html part from the meta fields and then added it in the function like your second option.

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue is resolved.